# How to use modify_headers extension for Firefox via Webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, browser-automation, ruby

I'm trying to use modify_headers extension (because this feature will [never be added to Webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141)) but without success.

I use the following code:

```
@profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

@profile.add_extension('extensions/modify_headers-0.7.1.1-fx.xpi')
@profile['modifyheaders.config.active'] = true
@profile['modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn'] = true
@profile['modifyheaders.config.openNewTab'] = true
@profile['modifyheaders.config.migrated'] = true

@profile['modifyheaders.headers.count'] = 1
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.action0'] = 'Add'
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.name0'] = 'some_name'
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.value0'] = 'some_value'
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.enabled0'] = true

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for :firefox, :profile => @profile
```

When I navigate to some page I see it as if I didn't modify header.
What was wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found which line of code causes this behavior:

```
@profile['modifyheaders.config.migrated'] = true
```

Final variant:

```
@profile.add_extension('support/add_ons/modify_headers-0.7.1.1-fx.xpi')
@profile['modifyheaders.config.active'] = true
@profile['modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn'] = true
@profile['modifyheaders.config.openNewTab'] = true
@profile['modifyheaders.start'] = true

@profile['modifyheaders.headers.count'] = 1
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.action0'] = 'Add'
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.name0'] = 'some_name'
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.value0'] = 'some_value'
@profile['modifyheaders.headers.enabled0'] = true

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for :firefox, :profile => @profile
```